# multiple entries in app.config or how to resolve dependency version conflict

Tags: .net, visual-studio, app-config

I am wondering is it possible to have multiple entries in `app.config` file?

I think I have 2 different libraries that each one is bringing in a different version of "Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager" so I am trying to resolve them via `app.config`.

This is my attempt but it has a syntax error:

```
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.17.3.0" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="3.13.1-preview" newVersion="3.17.3.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

Error message:

```
Application Configuration file "app.config" is invalid. There was a problem parsing the oldVersion attribute. Version string portion was too short or too long.
```

I am also wondering can we see dependency tree (either via command line or visual studio) to see which library is bringing in "Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a range instead:

```
<bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.17.3.0" newVersion="3.17.3.0"/>
```

More information [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/redirect-assembly-versions#specify-assembly-binding-in-configuration-files).